# Trouble shooting cooling system

Tags: troubleshooting, cooling-system, cooling

Is this the water pump, or what?
I have a 2008 Lincoln MKX and have been experiencing a leak from one of the hoses from the coolant tank or radiator for several months according to one mechanic.

It has gotten worse so I took it in and was told that I needed a new water pump. $1,350 later the car still overheats and is leaking coolant.

On top of that I failed to mention that there's some noise that is being made and when you shut the car off the noise continues for several seconds but since the new water pump has been put in that noise and time length has increased. That noise occurs when the engine is starting to get heated up. When it gets hotter it's even louder so when you shut the car off to prevent overheating is when it really makes that noise and the length of time you continue to hear that noise  is getting longer.

Also timing is off...when put it in gear it bucks a little into gear.  Like it jumps into gear and the car bucks forward. Took it back and and mechanic hooked up  something  (diagnostic  computer) under steering wheel but nothing.

Oh and I failed to mention my check engine light is on but wasn't before I took it in to get it fixed.  Of course the car  wouldn't make the noise because sometimes you think oh wait maybe  it's fixed itself. Wrong! He said just don't let your car idle and maybe it's something more, maybe the fan.

Why wouldn't he troubleshoot all possibilities of what issues are before just focusing on water pump.  He wants to know if I want him to explore and then fix new potential issue(s)?

What could be wrong with it? What should I do?

Comment: have you replaced tried replacing radiator cap ? or in spected system for a leak ?

Answer (score 1):

If you took your car in and asked for the water leak to be repaired, then that is what they will do.

They cannot fix every issue on the car "just because it is there" because you will refuse to pay for work done that was not asked for.

They cannot guess which issues you want fixed unless you point out all that you want done.

Sadly, getting it fixed for nothing is not an option... But working through the issues in terms of priority once you know what the mechanic finds may well be.

Comment: I said to him that I've had a slow leak for quite a while someone said that I could be the hose and it's overheating more and more so maybe it's time for it to be looked at. He called me later on in the day and had tested it and said it's your water pump once that's fixed everything should be all set